# Getting actual semicolon and array elements in url. Angular

Tags: angular

```js
  ngOnInit() {
        const id$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(map((params) => params.get('id') || 0), map(n => Number(n)));
        id$.subscribe(id => {
          this.activeId = id;
          console.log("ActiveId",this.activeId);
          this.testing =  this.graphService.getTestingGraphs(id);
          this.image = this.imageService.getImage(id);
        });
          this.route.params
          .subscribe(params => {
          const id = +params['id'];
          console.log(`Current param ID is: ${id}`);
    });
```

```html
<div *ngIf = "this.domain.id == 1" class ="row" >
    <button (click)="prev()" class="previous round">&#8249;</button>
      <div  [ngStyle] = "{'background-image': 'url('+ testing.url +')'}" class ="img-container">
      </div>
    <button (click)="next()" class="next round">&#8250;</button>
  </div>
```

I have a route that I want to link like this "http://localhost:4200/image/1;id=1;catergory=testing"
However when I try to hard code in the semicolon and the other contents of the array I get different values. I tried something like
this.router.navigate(['/image/' + next] + ';' + this.domain.id + ";" + "catergory=" + this.domain.catergory);

```js
  next() {
    // const next = this.activeId + 1 >= this.image.length - 1  ? this.graph.length - 1 : this.activeId + 1;
    const next = this.domain.id + 1 >= 9  ? 1 : this.domain.id + 1;
    this.router.navigate(['/image/' + next] + ";");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `Router#navigate` in a wrong way. If you want to add query params, you need to pass a `NavigationExtras` parameter after the URI you want to navigate to.

For example:

```
const extras: NavigationExtras = {
    queryParams: {
        id: this.domain.id,
        category: this.domain.category
    }
};
this.router.navigate(['image', next], extras);
```

Also please notice that the array you're passing is the URI fragments, therefore you don't need to use split fragments using a `'/'`. For that, you can use `Router#navigateByUrl`.

Comment: Am I grabbing the right url based on this then? Because this is the error I'm getting "property 'url' of undefined"

Comment: Supposedly. Try running this and let me know if it worked. Pretty sure Angular will use `?` for query params instead of `;` though.

Comment: Ok my last question. Based on my url i'm trying to grab the first id number. "image/id" however it does grab the first one but if I change the image it always returns 1. Why is that? I provided the code to the top. For example right after image/1 I would to to take the 1 as the id.

Comment: Why do you have an `*ngIf="this.domain.id == 1"`? By the way, remove `this` in the expression, it's not needed.

Comment: Ok thank you. Did you see my comment about getting the id number right after 'image/id'?

Comment: Based on my code it seems to get that domain id number "id".

Comment: I don't really understand. What ID are you trying to get? The next one? Aren't you increasing the value of `this.domain.id` to get the next one each time?